# python xlsxwriter worksheet object reuse

Tags: python, xlsxwriter

I've written some code that iterates through a flat file. After a certain section is completed reading, I take the data and put it into a spreadsheet. Then, I go back and continue reading the flat file for the next section and write to a new worksheet...and so on and so forth.

When looping through the python code, I create a new worksheet for each section read above. During this looping, I create the new worksheet as such:

worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet(thename)

The problem is that the second time through the loop, python crashes when re-assigning the worksheet object above to a new worksheet. Is there a way to "close the worksheet object", then re-assign it?

FYI: If I can't use the same object name, "worksheet" in this case, the code is going to become tremendously long and messy in order to handle "worksheet1", "worksheet2", "worksheet3", etc... (as you might imagine)

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The problem is that the second time through the loop, python crashes when re-assigning the worksheet object above to a new worksheet.

Python shouldn't crash when running an XlsxWriter program. If it does you should submit a bug report.

You can loop over worksheets in a few different ways. For example by creating the worksheet in the loop:

```
import xlsxwriter

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('test.xlsx')

for _ in range(4):

    worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

    worksheet.write('A1', 'Hello')

workbook.close()
```

Or by creating the worksheets outside the loop and then using the [`worksheets()`](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/workbook.html#workbook-worksheets) method to loop over them:

```
import xlsxwriter

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('test.xlsx')

workbook.add_worksheet()
workbook.add_worksheet()
workbook.add_worksheet()
workbook.add_worksheet()

for worksheet in workbook.worksheets():
    worksheet.write('A1', 'Hello')

workbook.close()
```

You could also store the worksheets in a list and iterate over that. That is essentially with the `worksheets()` method is doing.

Comment: Well, after testing with your examples...which worked fine...I did some more digging into my code and realized that there was a non-printable character in my data that was messing things up. Thank you for your examples...they are very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of assigning the variable `worksheet` to `workbook.add_worksheet(thename)`, have a list called `worksheets`. When you normally do `worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet(thename)`, do `worksheets.append(workbook.add_worksheet(thename))`. Then access your latest worksheet with `worksheets[-1]`.